# Rails and Twitter Bootstrap css: underscore or hyphen

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I noticed that rails uses underscores for css id/class names ("some__class_name"), but bootstrap uses hyphens ("some-class-name"). I want to be consistent in my use of id/class names. What's the best way to tackle this issue to have a consistent use of either underscores or hyphens? I can't seem to find any options to modify rails or bootstrap's css naming convention.

Comment: what do you mean by "rails uses underscores for id/class"?

Comment: I mean css id and class names use the naming convention "some_name" in rails, vs "some-name" in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I wasn't thinking about this clearly... must be getting late. Rails is getting the id name in my field tags from the symbol ":some_variable", and thus applying that name, with the underscore, to the id names. Looks like I just need to make sure to explicitly define the id name to use hyphens to conform with bootstrap's naming convention.

Comment: But then you'd have to rename all the Ruby variables to use hyphens which is breaking a Ruby convention. At least when using form_for. I don't think you can reach consistency here.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt full consisteny is possible here. You might use the chance to seperate your own css-classes from either twitter-bootstrap's or from rails's.
I'd suggest using underscores for your own css-names, as that puts rails's naming (a result of the Ruby convention) and your own in the same bucket, allowing for more consistency in your css files (based on the assumption that one is less likely to edit twitter bootstrap css-classes).

Another reason for that is that some editors don't autocomplete hyphen-seperated names.